# How to bash-script or simplify ffmpeg commands for resizing the watermark, adding it to the video and adding subtitle.ass to the video?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, ubuntu-18.04

I would like to create hard-subbed video with watermark by using ffmpeg. And I'd like to know how to combine and simplify multiple commands or how to create a bash-script for this purpose.

I've tried searching in stackflow and tested some commands but they didn't work. Here are the comands I'm using.

1. To detect video width & height:

   ```
   ffprobe -v quiet -show_entries stream=width,height -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 video_in.mp4
   ```
2. To resize the watermark image: (video width = 1280)

   ```
   ffmpeg -i watermark.png -y -v quiet -vf scale=1280*0.15:-1 watermark_scaled.png
   ```
3. To add watermark to the video:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i video_in.mp4 -i watermark_scaled.png -filter_complex "overlay=W-w-5:5" video_marked.mp4
   ```
4. To add .ass subtitle to the video: (it need to be '.ass')

   ```
   ffmpeg -i video_marked.mp4 -vf ass=subtitle.ass video_final.mp4
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to detect video dimensions. The [scale2ref](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale2ref) filter can resize input using a reference.

Here's all steps in one command.

```
ffmpeg -i video_in.mp4 -i watermark.png
       -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=iw*0.15:ow/mdar[wm][v];
                        [v][wm]overlay=W-w-5:5,ass=subtitle.ass"
       -c:a copy video_final.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks @Gyan for saving a lot of time. It works well. But when I use input video with 'webm' format, it shows the mp4 error. [mp4 @ 0x5651a0649400]

Comment: [mp4 @ 0x555f37d9a400] track 1: codec frame size is not set
[mp4 @ 0x555f37d9a400] opus in MP4 support is experimental, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Experimental feature
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --

Comment: Remove `-c:a copy` for such cases.

Comment: It works now. Thank you very much. Is it because of the audio stream from this webm (audio format = opus) cannot be used in mp4 container?